# C# After passing an object from window window I can´t acces object properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm coding an application that handles an inventory connected to an SQL database.  I'm coding the "admin" side of the app, and for important tasks, I ask the admin for his password to confirm changes. However, once I try to access the object property, I can't find any way of doing so. I'll explain step by step:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String Log { get; set; }
    public String Pwd { get; set; }
    public String User { get; set; }
    public Boolean Activo { get; set; }
    public Boolean Admin { get; set; }
    public Boolean Reportes { get; set; }

    public Usuario() { }

    public Usuario(int id, string User, bool Activo, bool Admin, bool Reports)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.User = User;
        this.Activo = Activo;
        this.Admin = Admin;
        this.Reportes = Reportes;
    }
}
```

So this is the User class I made. Then, when the application starts I have a password window which the code is the following:

```
public Pwd()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public Usuario UserA;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String res;
    Conexion c = new Conexion();
    res = c.Password(txUsuario.Text, txPassword.Text);
    if (res == "1")
    {
        UserA = (Usuario)usuarioActual(txUsuario.Text, txPassword.Text);
        if (UserA.Activo)
        {
            Menu m = new Menu();
            Menu.User = UserA;
            m.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario no está activo");
        }
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");        
}

public static Object usuarioActual(String user, String pass)
{
    int id;
    String User;
    Boolean Activo;
    Boolean Admin;
    Boolean Reporte;

    id = Id(user, pass);
    User = nombreUser(user, pass);
    Activo = estaActivo(user,pass);
    Admin = esAdmin(user, pass);
    Reporte = Reportes(user, pass);

    Usuario Actual = new Usuario(id, User, Activo, Admin, Reporte);

    return Actual;
}
```

So the main thing here is that I have a Public "UserA." The "usuarioActual" method creates a "new" user and saves it into the public UserA of the class

Then once the user and pwd are correct I open the next window and set the User to be the same as the new window user. As follows:

```
this.Hide();
Menu m = new Menu();
m.Show();
Menu.User = UserA;
```

So I just keep "bouncing" my user around between windows until I reach the one I want to use the pwd of my User

```
public Alta()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static Usuario UserA;
bool Activo = true;
bool Admin = false;
bool Reportes = true;
bool cambio = false;

private void btAlta_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String res;
    if (Campos())
    {
        res = Interaction.InputBox("Está por realizar un alta, para confirmarla escriba su contraseña:", "Confirmación");
        if (res.Equals(UserA.Pwd.ToString()))
        {
            altaUser(tbLogin, tbPass, tbNombre, Activo, Admin, Reportes);
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario agregado satisfactoriamente");
            cambio = true;
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Contraseña incorrecta intente de nuevo");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Existe algún error en los campos o quedaron vacíos");
}
```

So up here is the big deal. I just want to compare the response the user gave me in the inputbox vs the "User" .pwd property. I already tried:

```
if (res.Equals(UserA.Pwd.ToString()))
if (res.Equals(UserA.Pwd))
if (res == (UserA.Pwd.ToString())
if (res == UserA.Pwd)
```

But it throws me the "object reference not set to an object instance" error in every case, however:

I know that my object is being passed around since the very first time I pass it to my "Menu" window I use it to see if the user is an admin or not

```
public Menu()
{
    InitializeComponent();          
}
public static Usuario User;
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Admin)
    {
        PreAdmin a = new PreAdmin();
        PreAdmin.UserB = User;
        a.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("El usuario actual no tiene permiso de administrador");
}
```

And if I use

```
MessageBox.Show(UserA.ToString());
```

It shows:

```
WpfApplication_Almacen.Usuario
```

I would appreciate if anyone spots my error/the way I should do it. It's has slowed me down for a couple of hours now.

```
public PreAdmin()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static Usuario UserB;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Alta a = new Alta();
    Alta.UserA = UserB;
    a.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

So here's the order: `Usuario` -- > `Pwd` --> `Menu` --> `Pre-admin` --> `Alta`

The class `Pwd` is where the `Usario x = new Usuario` happens and never again in any part of my code. But as you can see I can use `User.Admin` in `Menu` but I don't find any way to access `User.Pwd` in the `Alta` class

Comment: For `MessageBox.Show(UserA.ToString());` to work the way you want, you would have to override `ToString()` method from object class in `Usuario`. And for `if (res.Equals(UserA.Pwd.ToString()))`, need more clarity about when it is called! Is it called after `Button_Click` because there is where `UserA` was initialized

Comment: I already edited the question if you want to take a further look

Comment: Well then, where did you initialize `UserA` for `Alta` before calling it in `btAlta_Click`?

Comment: @praty  I didn't do anything else like in my "Menu" window class. As you can see it let me check if User.Admin was true to run the code.  "User" comes from my "Pwd" window class. And "User" then goes to "PreAdmin" windows class from "Menu" and so on until it reaches my "Alta" window class.  How I can use my Object to check if it's admin ("Menu class") but I can't ask again for the .Pwd ("Alta" class) where in both cases the Object class comes and was initialized in another window ("Pwd" class) ?

Comment: @Reinaldo this race condition is caused because i'm using multiple windows? Is there any advice for it or something?

Comment: I have given a solution for your condition. Please do check and let know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will fix your issue.

First thing first, override `ToString()` for `Usuario`

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String Log { get; set; }
    public String Pwd { get; set; }
    public String User { get; set; }
    public Boolean Activo { get; set; }
    public Boolean Admin { get; set; }
    public Boolean Reportes { get; set; }

    public Usuario() { }

    public Usuario(int id,string User, bool Activo, bool Admin, bool Reportes)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.User = User;
        this.Activo = Activo;
        this.Admin = Admin;
        this.Reportes = Reportes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            "User ID: {1}{0} at {0}Name: {2}{0}Activo: {3}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            this.id,
            this.User,
            this.Activo);
    }
}
```

Now, about the object reference issue. I see that you have stored `Userio` object in a static variable for `Menu` in `Menu.User`. Hoping my perception is correct, you can edit your `btAlta_Click` as:

```
private void btAlta_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String res;

    if (Campos())
    {
        res = Interaction.InputBox("Está por realizar un alta, para confirmarla escriba su contraseña:", "Confirmación");

        // I would suggest to add this line of code
        if(UserA == null)
        {
            UserA = Menu.User;
        }

        if (res.Equals(UserA.Pwd.ToString()))
        {
            altaUser(tbLogin, tbPass, tbNombre, Activo, Admin, Reportes);
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario agregado satisfactoriamente");
            cambio = true;
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Contraseña incorrecta intente de nuevo");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Existe algún error en los campos o quedaron vacíos");
}
```

OR, You can edit the property for `Alta` as:

```
public static Usuario UserA 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Menu.User;
    }
}
```

Either of 2 solutions should work for you.

Missed to see you never set Pwd!

```
public static Object usuarioActual(String user, String pass)
{
    int id;
    String User;
    Boolean Activo;
    Boolean Admin;
    Boolean Reporte;

    id = Id(user, pass);
    User = nombreUser(user, pass);
    Activo = estaActivo(user,pass);
    Admin = esAdmin(user, pass);
    Reporte = Reportes(user, pass);

    Usuario Actual = new Usuario(id, User, Activo, Admin, Reporte);

    // You need to add this:
    Actual.Pwd = pass;

    return Actual;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I just keep on getting the same error message:  object reference not set to an object instance

Comment: @FernandoCossio Can you update your question to show where exactly is your `Alta` class initialized and used?

Comment: @FernandoCossio, I think the reason might be because you do `m.Show()` before setting `Menu.User`. Interchange there positions. Call `m.Show()` after setting `Menu.User` and check if it works.

Comment: @paty 1: I already updated my question to include the new class 2: I already updated the order on every .show()  3: Same error message at the line stated in the question. (I want to thank you for sticking with me!)

Comment: @FernandoCossio, Happy to help. In your updated question, I still see `a.Show()` before setting `Alta.UserA = UserB;`!

Comment: It's totally updated now. Last time I just added the missing class you asked for

Comment: Found the issue @FernandoCossio! You did never set the `Pwd`. Updated my answer under "Missed to see you never set Pwd!"

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot now, I now remeber I didn't stored hthe password to minizme information leaks.... oh well, the everyday life of a programmer. Really really thank you! I was stuck for hours now and I could bet I wouldn´t noticed it untill I dicided to start my class from scratch. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FernandoCossio I can understand we miss setting up properties sometimes :). Please mark this as an answer if it helped you. I had a piece of advice for you as well. If you are coding for a production application I would recommend you to follow secure coding protocols as this solution is pretty insecure and hack-able. There are a lot of resources available online that can help you. Happy coding :).